# Rails 4 - How to properly display times across timezones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, utc

I am working on an application where users create events. For every event, I use a countdown - so on the page is shown how much time (hours, minutes and seconds) left to the beginning of the event.

I am in the Netherlands (+1h), so when I create an event and set its start on March 29th, 19:45 and then look to the database, I see there following (the column is `datetime`):

```
2015-03-29 19:45:00
```

But when I load the page, it shows that the event will start always in 1 more hour. How to handle this behavior?

Also, I wanted to ask one more thing - let's say I set start of an event on 19:45h. How to ensure that someone browsing my website in California (that's 9 hours behind the Netherlands) will see the proper time (this person should see beginning of the event on 10:45 and not 19:45).

Thank you, I haven't been doing some serious work with time/zones.

PS: the server I use for the app is located in Amsterdam (a DigitalOcean server).

Comment: Are you saying the time shown is always one hour later than the time in the database? Can you show some code so we can see what methods you're using?

Comment: @JoshLeitzel just like this `= e.event_start` - if I print the datetime out like this, how the datetime will see a person in California? As 19:45 or 10:45?

Comment: have you found any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are saving the time in utc inside your db tables and setting the application time as GMT. Check your Time.zone in rails console.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that Rails uses timezone of your server unless you specified it explicitly in configuration of your app.

To support behavior that will enable you to render proper times across different timezones, you need to understand in which TZ user is (to show it properly).

For this you have 2 options:

**Option B** (backend + frontend)

- store time in DB in UTC
- set application's default time zone to be UTC (this will make it render in UTC)
- on the frontend using JS convert record's datetime to user's timezone (you can use [Moment Timezone JS library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/))

**Option B** (all server-side)

- store time in DB in UTC
- get user's timezone (i.e. store User's timezone in profile settings)
- convert UTC datetime from record to user's timezone and render

I would recommend **Option A** especially if you don't have user profiles this may be the only viable way to build this functionality.